# Splitting a string having comma separated and a text qualifier using perl

Tags: string, perl, split

I need to split the below string using the perl, the details are given below. I need to load the data to a table from the CSV file. The string variables are enclosed in "". Please provide me an idea, I am new to perl scripting.

String : `"February 6, 2012","","","1","02/06/12","","",1,1,0`

output :

```
February 6, 2012
<BLANK VALUE>
<BLANK VALUE>
1
02/06/12
<BLANK VALUE>
<BLANK VALUE>
1
1
0
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a "write my code for me" forum. Show us what you have and we'll help you improve it.

Answer (score 8):

This looks a lot like CSV. If it is then please do yourself and us a favor and use an appropriate module for it instead of regular expressions. There is the excellent [Text::CSV_XS](http://search.cpan.org/~hmbrand/Text-CSV_XS-0.92/CSV_XS.pm).

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to split it. Each item that you want to split should be wrapped in a group, like this

```
^\"(.*?)\",\"\",\"\",\"(.*?)\",\"(.*?)\",\"\",\"\",(\d),(\d),(\d)
```

expression in the bracket it's a group, then you can get groups in code.

Comment: Regexes like that are an excellent advert for using modules like Text:CSV :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $ac = qq("February 6, 2012","","","1","02/06/12","","",1,1,0);

$ac=~s/\"//ig;
my @arr = split(',', $ac);
$arr[0] .= $arr[1];
print $arr[0] . "\n"; # the date is February 6, 2012

# print other elements
for (my $i=2; $i < @arr; $i++) {
    if ($arr[$i] eq '') {print "<BLANK VALUE>\n";}
    else {print $arr[$i] . "\n";}
}
```

Comment: Are there commas inside the quotes by any chance? If not, split on the comma and remove the leading and ending quotes from all fields. Is this a CSV file? If so, use Text::CSV module to do the dirty work for you.